# String reference in the C language

Tags: c, string, memory

let's say I create a char *s = "something" and then I assign another variable s1 = s, would s1 take the memory reference of s or would it go to another memory chunk and copy the "value" of s so that it has a reference on its own?

Comment: Are you in C++?

Comment: No, I'm in C language

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, sorry being unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using C and not C++, a "string" is actually a pointer to a character (presumably, an array of characters actually, but, formally "a character"). So, assigning "strings" is assigning pointers and there will be no copy of the memory pointed to (by said pointer) involved.

```
char const* s = "whatev";
char const* s2 = s; // both s and s2 point to the same memory 
                // that "holds" the 'w' (followed by `hatev` and NUL character)
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, there is no string type. Strings in C are just arrays of characters. A string variable is declared to be of type `char *`, which is a pointer to a char (array).

Therefore, the assignment `s1 = s` will just copy the pointer from s to s1, i.e a memory reference, and not a copy of the string data.

If you want to copy the string, you can use the `strdup()` function, which will allocate memory and copy the string data to it. Remember to `free()` the memory afterwards.